# Give a Windows 2008 VM Internet access but block Host LAN access?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, routing, virtual-machines

[Securing a guest VM to give it internet access, but block access to host LAN](https://serverfault.com/questions/517490/securing-a-guest-vm-to-give-it-internet-access-but-block-access-to-host-lan)

The above was a similar question asked for Linux but the following has specifics that are different.

We need to have this VM (clone from a key server/ DC) Updated (via the Internet) to test something but not allow this clone to access the Host LAN & other machines.

The VM is Windows SBS 2008 and is on a Test Box running Win 2012 R2 with both: Hyper V and VMWare (being able to switch in between).

Currently it is inside VMWare Workstation 10.0 but we've also had a cloned one inside Hyper V as well.

So whichever way is easier to make this happen please do point out.

Answer (score 1):

hi Probonnonprofi :) ,

NAT is not an option for Adapter Type. Rather, it's an option for Attached to.

Click where it currently says Bridged Adapter and you should be able to select NAT.

By the way, the reason changing it to NAT sometimes helps is not specific to Windows guests. Rather, if your physical (host) PC is on a LAN, Bridged Adapter (as well as NAT) usually works fine. If your physical PC has a network connection for just one computer--as is often the case if it's plugged directly into a cable/DSL/ISDN modem that only has one Ethernet port on it--then there is no local network to bridge to, so then you must use NAT.

If you use Bridged Adapter and your host machine is on a physical LAN, your guest machine will automatically be able to see and be seen by computers on the LAN. If you use NAT on a LAN, the guest machine will be able to see the other computers on the LAN but the other computers on the LAN (besides the virtualization host) will not be able to see it.